# How to move image to its original position in android?

Tags: android, image, audio, move, tap

I am playing a sound track when an image is moved by a finger.
I want to move the image to its original position when sound track stops playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how are you moving the image over the screen but saving the original position should be enough.

Comment: i am moving the position of image up and down.